# how do i get all my object instances as an int

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

i am creating a ToDo app and i want to calculate the percentage of activities completed based on the total activities set

my views.py

```
def progress(request):
    todo1 = int(ToDo.objects.all().count())
    complete1 = int(ToDo.objects.filter(completed=True))
    todo = int(todo1)
    complete = int(complete1)
    percent = complete // todo * 100
    context = {
        'percent' : percent,
    }
    return render(request, 'percent.html', context)
```

but i receive a TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'QuerySet'

i really need help

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to count the number of `completed=True` `ToDo`s:

```
def progress(request):
    todo = ToDo.objects.count()
    complete = ToDo.objects.filter(completed=True).count()  # ← count the number of elements
    percent = complete * 100 // todo
    context = {
        'percent' : percent,
    }
    return render(request, 'percent.html', context)
```